# How do adjust the background property of top layout

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout

I have a linearLayout as the main layout in my android xml file. The background is set to "@drawable/window_background_red". Inside the activity (at run time) I want to set this to "@drawable/window_background_green".

window_background_green.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:type="linear"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#004400"
                android:angle="-90"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say that for linearLayout `android:id="@+id/linearLayout"`
then in code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.window_background_green);
```

And there, you've set the background to be `@drawable/window_background_green`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason "R.id.linearLayout" was throwing an error. I came back a few hours later and it worked, not sure what was going on.

Comment: Idk. I've had weird, unexplainable things happen before, too. Sometimes uninstalling, re-installing the app (or factory resetting the phone) helps. Glad I could help.

Comment: That, or if go to Project > Clean and then run it again that fixes it. Maybe one your R.id.linearLayout somehow was messed up in the generated file.