# Java/Android: Set Background Color of Form/Screen

Tags: android

I can set my text color using heading.setTextColor(Color.RED); but I cant seem to find reference anywhere on how to set the background color of the Form/Screen.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setBackgroundColor`

I got the info from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor

Comment: View mlayout = findViewById(R.id.start_linear);   mlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));