# Change Layout-background on click programmatically

Tags: android, xml, response

I can change the background of a LinearLayout via xml by writing

> android:background="@drawable/overview"

to my LinearLayout.

However I can't do that programmatically. I tried following:

> LinearLayout horizontal_menu = new LinearLayout(this);
>   ...
>      horizontal_menu.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getInteger(R.drawable.overview));

and also that source of code:

> horizontal_menu.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.overview));

First try throws an RuntimeException at runtime, the second line seems to do nothing -> no errors, no exceptions, no changing background on clicking...

--> overview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/half_transparent"/> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/half_transparent" />
</selector>
```

I hope that anyone can help me!

Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout); 
LinearLayout horizontal_menu = new LinearLayout(this); 
horizontal_menu.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 
horizontal_menu.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getInteger(R.drawable.overv‌​iew)); 
content.addView(horizontal_menu);
```

Comment: You have an ansewer in topics:

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961071/android-changing-background-color-of-the-activity-main-view?lq=1   
Try those possibillities and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 9):

Set an id for layout in your layout XML file:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout" ...
```

and then in your Activity, get LinearLayout with findViewById() as below:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
```

And then set background for ll with setBackground methods:

```
ll.setBackground(...) 
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(...)
ll.setBackgroundResource(...)
```

Comment: not working. state change is not triggered. any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and Based on my search there is no way to change activity or main ViewGroup styles dynamically after `super.onCreate` .so you should either have a XML layout and set that layout before `super.onCreate` or you should inflate that layout like this:

```
root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.one,root);
```

note that you should have a root view to parent the layout you inflate.
and when you want to change that layout just do this:

```
buttonclick{
        root.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.two,root);
        root.addView(v,0);
}
```

note that you could add or remove each widget or view by `viewGroup.addView` also but in my opinion `Inflater` is much more better choice.

EDIT:

for very nice answer in this regard see @broot answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334048/android-layout-replacing-a-view-with-another-view-on-run-time).