# Setting Background Colour to PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I am having a confusion regarding setting of a background colour in my preference activity. My settingsactivity doen't have any layout.xml attached with it and thus generated everything from the headers.xml and preferences.xml. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961125/5863472) answer in my onCreate method of my settingsactivity class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(0xFF111321);
}
```

Using this I can see the change in my [preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Ewf.png) (sorry for the colour) but my [headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qyVu.png) headers stay the same. To change the background of my headers I have to write:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(0xFF111321);
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF111321);
}
```

Also if I don't use `getWindow()` the opposite happens.

Why is this happening?
I hate writing duplicate code for the same functionality, is there any way to do the requirement with a single code.

N.B. `getWindow()` also works with my other activities.