# Make whole screen white(or any color)

Tags: android

I have an alarm Receiver which do some work at the time which the user sets in an Activity. I want to make all screen white when the class Receives alarm!! . Is it possible? How can I do that? I have searched in google and found some answers to make application full screen! I don't know what should i search for my goal.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // make whole screen white(or any color)
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961071/android-changing-background-color-of-the-activity-main-view

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if(MainActivity.getInstace()!=null)
                MainActivity.getInstace().updateUI();
}
```

and make a public function in YourActivity where you want to FULL COLOR SCREEN

```
public void updateUI() {
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //DO YOUR CHANGE
         //put background color in main layout
        }
    });
}
```

Make an activity with receiver and UI, so need to make a separate receiver.

Hope this hint helps you..