# How would I change the background colour using an if statement from settings?

Tags: java, android, xml, if-statement, settings

I have researched this problem and found out that an if statement is needed.
This is the xml section
pref_general.xml

```
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="Red"
    android:entries="@array/entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/values"
    android:key="example_list1"
    android:title="@string/preferencebackground" />
```

What would you place in the java to change the background colour. E.g. if setting list preference color = black then `android:background="#000000"`
Else if list preference color = green... etc.

Comment: Use Drawable Selector

Comment: Are you asking about how to write the if-condition or what to put in the if-body?

Comment: What to put in the if-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would you place in the java to change the background colour?

Do you mean how to set the background color at runtime?

If you want to change the background color of a view, you can do

```
View v; // the view you want to change the color...you can findViewById
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

To change the color of the whole activity, see [How to set background color of an Activity to white programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically).

Or if you want to change a whole theme at runtime, try [How to change current Theme at runtime in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)