# Change the backgrond color of my main activity using java and not xml

Tags: android

I want to change the background colour of my main activity using Java code.
Help me with some code snippets!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of so many questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically

Comment: Dear they suggest using xml and buttons. I want to do it in oncreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(int) (if you are setting it to a color)
```

//This function also can be used to Views;

Example :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

// background set to RED. **MUST BE USED ONLY IN MAIN THREAD!**

Comment: the method setBackgroundColor(int) needs to be called. Which variable should be used to do that

Comment: @PANDA i m using eclipse Helios.this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); is not available in onCreate()

Comment: is Color xml available in res folder? if not use for example .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"))

Comment: Sorry. I have a mistake and updated a answer. See above.

Comment: @Stacks28 No Color xml in res... I want to change through Java code

Comment: .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd")) use whatever color u want search color code appropriately

Comment: @PANDA Thanks!! it worked. But what if i want to use thread which keep changing my screen background color

Answer (score 0):

If you want permanently changing color of you're Activity you must implementing two things :

```
1)Handler
2)Thread which cnanging color
```

```
Handler h = new Handler();
```

in Handler implements handleMessage method. 
In handleMessage Method use

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);//or msg.what
```

in **run** method use h.sendMessage(0); //or Color int value **0 in that case is a msg.what**

Unfortunately i do not have on hand IDE to give you full example.