# How change activity background color

Tags: android, colors, background

I have button called color. How can I change the Activity background color every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Quick google search:
[How to set background color of an Activity to white programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically)

Put that in a loop with a `Thread.sleep(5000)` and wrap it with a function that sets the colors you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not sleep a thread , its a bad practice** Create the object of your parent view in layout
and use Async task to update the UI after a fixed interval in below method

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // interact with UI here
     }
```

[see the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for AsyncTask implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TimerTask`

e.g.

```
Time timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                  //here set background
                }
                },0,5000);
```

For more details, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html