# How to set/change Android Studio 'Fullscreen Activity' background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I created a new activity using the 'Fullscreen Activity' template in Android Studio. I now want to change the background which is set to `android:background="#0099cc"` by default in its generated XML file. However, I've tried the 'solution' on one of the more popular, similar questions but got a error.

[How to set background color of an Activity to white programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically)

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2060)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1625)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16251)
```

which happens at the `root.setBackgroundResource(Color.WHITE);` line. Below is the entirety of the java code with the only two things added to the Activity template being the onStart method and a setActivityBackgroundColor() method.

```
package org.test.app;

import org.test.app.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.test.app.R;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenActivityTest extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_activity_test);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setActivityBackgroundColor();
    }

    public void setActivityBackgroundColor() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_activity_test);

        View root = ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        root.setBackgroundResource(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }


    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) takes a resource, not a color (even though both are integers). You probably want to use [View.setBackgroundColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)) if you want to set it to a color in code.