# Difference between android:windowBackground and android:colorBackground?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

What is the difference between `android:windowBackground` and `android:colorBackground`?

Example:

```
<style name = "theme">
 <item name ="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
 <item name ="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Which one would affect the color you see when a new activity is loading?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`windowBackground` only affects the main window's background.

`colorBackground` affects not only the background of the main window but also of all components e.g. dialogs unless you override it in the component layout.

So both of them change the activity's background, but the `colorBackground` changes many more things as well.

Answer (score 8):

> windowBackground are style properties that are effective only when the style is applied as a theme to an Activity or application and android:windowBackground attribute only supports a reference to another resource; unlike android:colorBackground, it can not be given a color literal

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

EDITED:
i.e. the value of windowBackground must be a referenced color:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>
```

but for backgroundColor you can use literals:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">#ff0000</item>
```

Comment: And how does that differ from colorBackground? What is colorBackground doing then?  I've already read that documentation and I don't think it answers the question I asked.  Thanks for an answer though!

Comment: Okay I guess I asked my question poorly because what I really don't understand is what `android:colorBackground` is doing.  So I guess my original question should be "What does setting `android:windowBackground`do and what does setting `android:colorBackground` do? Are they different?"  You have answered the difference between how they can be used, but I'm still unsure what they are used for, and the difference between what they actually do.

Comment: It does not seem that android:colorBackground can take a color literal anymore. I just downloaded aAndroid Studio, set up a new project targeting down to Android 4.0.3, and tried to set android:colorBackground to a color literal. It did not work to set the color. However setting it to a color resource did work as expected.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT Also, `android:colorBackground` is no longer mentioned in the link Sina provided