# Style displayed in emulator but not on my device

Tags: android, xml

I've following `style.xml` in `res/values/` folder:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#000000</item>
</style>
```

and the following layout for my main activity, where I've used `style="@style/AppTheme"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    style="@style/AppTheme"                                       // here I've used It.
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kaushal28.wakeupplease.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/startAlarm" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:text="Stop"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've device with Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean and emulator has latest Marsh mellow. I think the problem is because of this difference only. I've minimum SDK version 15 for this project.

I tried to change `targetSDKVersion` to 15 in `Build.Gradle`. But it couldn't solve my problem.

What should be displayed:
[image: Image of Emulator.]

What is displaying:
[image]

I'm expecting Black color in background.

Comment: What is not being customized? Is it possible to share some screenshots?

Comment: @GuilhermeP see the screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `android:windowBackground` instead of `android:colorBackground`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

**Why?**

By your screen, I saw that you are trying to set window background. So, the best attribute to that is `android:windowBackground`.

Your `AppTheme` is not overriding `android:windowBackground`.. it was only overriding `android:colorBackground`.

Since you are not overriding `android:windowBackground`, Android will use the color defined in your parent theme (`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`).

So, Android was using:

```
<item name="colorBackgroundFloating">@color/background_floating_material_light</item>
```

and

```
<color name="background_material_light">@color/material_grey_50</color>
<color name="material_grey_50">#fffafafa</color>
```

It is almost a white color.

**Device vs Studio**

I'll be honest.. I'm not totally sure why your device was ignoring `android:colorBackground` while emulator was using it...

Probably, is the API version or probably, it is just a normal behavior since your device shows the theme applied to an Activity and inside a whole context.. Your device will be always a little bit different from Android Studio Layout Preview tool.

For any instance, I recommend to use `android:windowBackground` if you want to sent whole window background...

`android:colorBackground` can affects not only the background of the main window but also of all the components e.g. dialogs unless you override it in the component layout. (this part was retrieved from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945383/4860513))

Comment: For all parameters I've to find such alternatives while using styles?