# Set initial background color before loading

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I set background color of an activity before `setContentView`.
I have an activity which takes lot of time to load, I need to keep background white until activity finishes loading.

Comment: Try to add spinner in that activity and make the background transparent

Comment: Make `rootView` Background White till your Loading and then make it different color after loading done

Comment: @MD I tried this `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);` but it's not working.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi What is this id `android.R.id.content` ?

Comment: Related: [How to set background color of Activity to white programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4761686)

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following:

`setContentView` can be called multiple times in activity lifecycle, So you can simply set another layout file which just shows the background as you require, and once you are done loading, call `setContentView` again to load the actual layout!

**OR**

You can simply manage all this in one layout file, by giving white background color to your root view than show/hide desired section as required!

Comment: @MD thanks, I have also added your suggestion as another option.

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate add the following

```
Spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.LoginPageProgressBar);
    Spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and when you click the button add the following before using intent

```
Spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score -1):

From Documentation

> setContentView(int layoutResID)
>
> Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be
>   inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

So , it is not possible to give some background color before  `setContentView()`

But try to

- Avoid too much code in `onCreate()` of `Activity` .
- Use `AsyncTask` to load Data & show a `progressbar` to the user
- Or you can implement some `splash screen` before loading the main `Activity`.